# Cant set Body of Post request using Angular HttpClient edit i am not able to make(put,delete,post any request only get is working)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am new to Angular and Node I made Rest endpoint in NodeJS which looks like this 
(update it works but only if i set the header of the request to application/x-www-form-urlencoded but then the requst body looks like {{"roleName":"new role"}: ""} this instaed of {roleName: "newRole"})

```
public static routes(app: Application): void {
  app
    .route("/roles")
    .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
      RoleC.allRoles().then(roles => res.status(200).send(roles));
    })
    .post((req: Request, res: Response) => {
      console.log(req);
      res.status(200).send(req.body);
      // RoleC.addRole(req.body.roleName).then(r => res.status(200).send(r));
    });
}
```

and I am making a post request from an angular application which looks like this

```
addRole(role: Role) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(role));
  this.http
    .post(this.baseURL, role)
    .subscribe(e => console.log("r", e), err => console.log("er", err));
}
```

But the problem is I am unable to set the body of the request when using postman it works as it should but from angular, the body is always empty I even tried using fetch instead but the same issue is even tried setting the headers and methods in node app like this

```
this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
this.app.all("*", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"
  );
  next();
});
```

but still, no success in making post request, however, get request works fine and I tries making a post request to  this URL from json placeholder https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts it works fine I am unable to figure out what is the bug and I know the json link works cause it gives bakes the body of the request in the response and if i dont use JSON.Stringify i get corse error but as per the documentation is should work fine but it wont the get request looks like this

```
 Roles(): Observable<object> {
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
});
return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
```

}

if i add {headers:httpHeader} with the requst i get cors error but if use it without it it works fine. cant make put delete or post request but they work in postman i even tried setting the content-type and Alloe-Acccess headers but nothing seems to be working

this is the angular service where i am making the request

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Role } from "./../models/role/role";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
 providedIn: "root"
})
export class RoleService {
readonly baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/roles";
updateRole: Subject<Role[]> = new Subject<Role[]>();
private roles: Role[] = [];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
get Roles(): Observable<object> {
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
});
return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
}
 getRole(id: number): Role {
 return this.roles[id];
}
addRole(role: Role) {
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(role));
this.http
  .post(this.baseURL, role, { headers: httpHeaders })
  .subscribe(e => console.log("r", e), err => console.log("er", err));
//this.updateRole.next(this.Roles);
}
}
```

this is the node code

```
import * as express from "express";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import IndexRoutes from "./routes/indexRoute";
import TestRoutes from "./routes/testRoute";
import UsersRoutes from "./routes/userRoute";
import RoleRoutes from "./routes/roleRoute";
import DepartmentRoutes from "./routes/department";
import RemunerationRoutes from "./routes/remunerationRouter";
import PayRoutes from "./routes/payRoute";
import FacultyRoutes from "./routes/FacultyRoute";
class App {
public app: express.Application;
constructor() {
this.app = express();
this.config();
IndexRoutes.routes(this.app);
TestRoutes.routes(this.app);
UsersRoutes.routes(this.app);
RoleRoutes.routes(this.app);
DepartmentRoutes.routes(this.app);
FacultyRoutes.routes(this.app);
RemunerationRoutes.routes(this.app);
PayRoutes.routes(this.app);
this.error();
}

 private config(): void {
 this.app.all("*", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
  next();
});
  this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
}
 private error(): void {
this.app.use((req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(404).send({
    msg: <string>`404 ${req.path} not fount`
  });
});
}
}
export default new App().app;
```

if i set header for get request even that brakes it

Comment: What does this line `console.log(JSON.stringify(role));` in your `addRole` method log to the console?

Comment: yes was using it to see that the data is getting there or not

Comment: My question is, **WHAT** does it print on to the console? Can you please add the content that is logged to your question?

Comment: the console.log in angular code prints "{"roleName":"newRole"}" (newRole is what i pass) and the console log in node part prints the request object with an empty body

Comment: {"roleName":"d"} it logs this

Comment: Have you tried setting the httpheadrs options for Content-Type?

Comment: yes i did if i set the content-type i get cors error no matter is the data is object or json i.e i get cors error no matter if i do JSON.stringify or not

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify the body, you can pass the object itself. Just remove `console.log(JSON.stringify(role));` and try.

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/roles' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: If the get request is working fine, can you please add the code to the question. You also need to fix whatever CORS error you are getting by adding proper headers to the request.

Comment: try setting in both angular and node

Comment: if i do it in angular even get request gives cors error

Comment: if i add content type in angular i get cors error even if i do stringify

Answer (score 0):

In your node js code try putting allow origin middle layer part before you are reading body of incoming request. That means you have to move body parser middle layer after allow origin part.For angular code in header just add content type. This is a guess, give this a try. Maybe this will help you.

---angular code---

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};
this.http
  .post(this.baseURL, role,httpOptions )
 .subscribe(e => console.log("r", e), err => console.log("er", err));
 }
```

Comment: did that it works but only if set header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded but then the body looks like this {{"roleName":"new"}: ""} insted of {roleName: "new"}

Comment: what is content type in your angular application?

Comment: please show us the full angular code. including where you are setting the header.

Comment: did se the qustion

Comment: if i dont set any headers i dont get cors error but then the body is not getting set

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check that out hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you backend is nodejs make sure you install "cors" :

```
npm install --save cors 
npm install --save @types/cors 
import cors from 'cors';
app.use(cors());
```

2) If you can read your body make sure you install "body-parser" :

```
npm install --save body-parser 
npm install --save @types/body-parser
import bodyParser , {urlencoded} from 'body-parser';
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If the problem still exist check HttpInterceptor